# Cassandra read timout

Tags: java, cassandra

I am new to Cassandra(3.7) with java. I have successfully configured with 3 Cassandra nodes and data retrieval with java connector also done when records near to 300 000.

But I loaded more data in Cassandra near to 4 million records at the time unable to query the result from Cassandra with java code (get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCddc.png)) . I am getting below error.

> **Error :** Cassandra failure during read query at consistency LOCAL_ONE (1 responses were required but only 0 replica responded, 1
>   failed)]]

In my Cassandra configuration :

**Machine 1 configuration**
 Heap size : 24 GB, new heap size : 800M, concurrent_reads: 16, concurrent_writes: 64, concurrent_counter_writes: 16

**Machine 2 configuration** 
  --> Heap size : 8 GB and new heap size : 600M, concurrent_reads: 16, concurrent_writes: 48, concurrent_counter_writes: 16

**Machine 3 configuration** 
  --> Heap size : 8 GB and new heap size : 600M, concurrent_reads: 16, concurrent_writes: 48, concurrent_counter_writes: 16

Comment: Can you run nodetool to get ring status [./nodetool -h yourip status] and print the results ?

Comment: Also run nodetool tpstats command during your query execution to check statistics about the number of active, pending, and completed tasks.

Comment: [root@localhost bin]# ./nodetool -h 192.168.1.23 status
nodetool: Failed to connect to '192.168.1.23:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused'.----> we got this issue

Comment: Is jmx port is active ? check cassandra-env.sh file -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=7199 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

Comment: I'd be curious to see the table definition and query that is running.  Many times issues like this are caused by bad models and/or bad queries.